# how to duplicate value textboxt html with currency format?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to copy the contents of the value from the textbox 1 to the textbox 2 with the respective id of bayar and destination. I use a library for the currency format.

```js
function copyValue() {
  var n1 = document.getElementById('bayar').value;

  var rupiahFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('id-ID', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'IDR',
  }).format(n1);
  console.log(rupiahFormat);

  document.getElementById('destination').value = rupiahFormat;

}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="bayar" id="bayar" class="form-control" onkeyup="copyValue()" />
<input type="number" name="destination" id="destination" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Your formatted value is a **string** which cannot be set into `<input type="number">`. Remove the `type` attribute on `#destination` and it will work

Comment: thx sir it works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

norally you use the event for that like addEventListsener and use the event you need for that

I have show you a example and it work

```js
let n1 = document.getElementById('bayar');
let n2 = document.getElementById('destination');

n1.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Correction : c'est "e.preventDefault();" et non "e.prenvent.default"
  n2.value = e.target.value; // Correction : c'est "e.target.value" pour obtenir la valeur de l'élément n1
  console.log(n2.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="bayar" id="bayar" class="form-control" />
    <input type="number" name="destination" id="destination" class="form-control" />
```

I wish you a good day

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to format the value as currency

Comment: it is just for show him one way to do it after he implement like he wants into his code

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question at all. OP's code works just fine with one small correction that isn't even present in this answer