# React input number out of range

Tags: reactjs

Hello I tried to format number while I am typing in react using input type number element.
But it keeps telling me out of range
The error occurred when the digit number above 4, and automatically reset to empty input

[image]

```js
/*  Format IDR */
function formatNumber(amount) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('id-id').format(amount)
}

const [lendData, setLendData] = useState({
    lendValue: 0,
    lendFee: 0,
  })

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  function handleChange(e) {
    let { name, value } = e.target
    setLendData((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value,
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<input
  type='number'
  name='lendValue'
  id='lendValue'
  placeholder='0'
  value={formatNumber(lendData.lendValue)}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: `<input type="number">` is not suitable for formatted values

Comment: @Phil is there any suggestion for that? I also have problem with suffix character `%` , like giving the output on the input like '1%'

Comment: Formatted numbers are text, so use `type="text"`

Comment: Exact same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77169872/283366) (ignore the answer though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you treat `number` as string.
The type `number` of the input cannot have commas (or other separators).

`value={formatNumber(lendData.lendValue)}` this part of your code throws the error in your console on the screenshot because you're trying to assign `string` to the `number` type input.

If you want to force a user to be able to type numbers only,

- you need to control it inside `onChange` handler

```js
// example
function handleChange(e) {
    let { someValue } = e.target.value;
    // this will remove any letter that is not a number
    someValue = someValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    
    setSomeState(someValue);

}
```

- if it's mobile, then try using `inputMode` and `pattern` attributes.

You can fix it by changing the input type as `text`

```js
<input
  pattern="[0-9]*" // for
  inputMode="numeric" // mobile
  type='text'
  name='lendValue'
  id='lendValue'
  placeholder='0'
  value={formatNumber(lendData.lendValue)}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

---

### Added

let me give you exact codes

1. change `type='number'` to `type='text'`
2. onChange handler

```js
function handleChange(e) {
  let { name, value } = e.target;
  value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

  setLendData((prev) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried but the error still the same

Comment: @flyingduck92 I updated my answer. Will you try again with it?

Comment: It works if I removing `pattern="[0-9]*"` man, but it still accept number 0  at the beginning is there a way to prevent accepting number 00 at the beginning ?

Comment: @flyingduck92 Sure there is. I think you need to work with the regex inside the onChange handler. Maybe you can use `noValidate` attribute in form element, then the pattern won't take any affect as far as I am concerned. And then use RegEx to test the string inside the onChange handler. For instance, try `/^[1-9][1-9]\d+$/.test(str)`. It will return false if there are two zeros at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I have similar question about decimal number and % character at input too. Can you help? its in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77331981/react-how-to-make-input-cursor-stay-before-symbol