# React - How to make input cursor stay before % symbol?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I made an input that show percentage like 1.1% (and not accepting 00 at the beginning) when typing but the cursor goes to the end while typing.
is there a away to keep it before % symbol

[image]

```js
function formatPercent(amount) {
  return amount + '%'
}

const [lendData, setLendData] = useState({
    lendValue: '',
    lendFee: '',
  })

function handleChange(e) {
    let { name, value } = e.target

    if (name == 'lendValue') {
      // prevent first character if it 0 and removing separator
      value = value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9]/g, '')

      setLendData((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [name]: value,
        }
      })
    } else if (name == 'lendFee') {
      // prevent first character if it 0
      value = value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9,.]/g, '')
      console.log(value)
      setLendData((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [name]: value,
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<input
  type='text'
  inputMode='decimal'
  name='lendFee'
  id='lendFee'
  placeholder='0%'
  value={
    lendData.lendFee ? formatPercent(lendData.lendFee) : ''
  }
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Make the "%" a label after the input, not in the input.

Comment: @mykaf the label not stick to the end of input value, that's why need to suffix the % at the end of value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```js
function formatPercent(amount) {
  return amount + '%';
}

function App() {
  const [lendData, setLendData] = useState({
    lendValue: '',
    lendFee: '',
  });

  const lendFeeInput = useRef(null);

  function handleChange(e) {
    let { name, value } = e.target;

    if (name === 'lendValue') {
      // prevent first character if it 0 and removing separator
      value = value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9]/g, '');

      setLendData((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [name]: value,
        };
      });
    } else if (name === 'lendFee') {
      const cursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart;

      // prevent first character if it 0
      value = value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9,.]/g, '');

      setLendData((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [name]: value,
        };
      });

      // Restoring cursor position
      setTimeout(() => {
        lendFeeInput.current.selectionStart = cursorPosition;
        lendFeeInput.current.selectionEnd = cursorPosition;
      }, 0);
    }
  }
```

**Explanation of the code changes:**

- I have used `useRef` hook and created a ref for the input element `lendFeeInput`.
- I stored the current cursor position before updating the input value:
  `const cursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart;`
- Finally I have restored the cursor position after updating the input value using `setTimeout` to ensure the input value has been updated.

**[CODE DEMO](https://playcode.io/1635997)**

Comment: Thanks man it stop before %. But it still able to passed the '%' with the arrow key. Also if I type in alphabet/symbol character the caret still moving to the right side. Is it possible to make it not able to passed the '% by any chance like the click/arrow key? If I click outside the input and click it again it still goes to the end of % character, and need 2x backspace to delete the value

Comment: @flyingduck92 I was answering your original question, so couldn't look at the logic which you applied to get this done. Let me try that

Comment: it means if I try typing in a alphabet characters the cursor moved to right side like the next character until the end of value

Comment: @flyingduck92 I have updated the code. Can you take a look if it helps? So now if enter any letter or special character other than `,` and `.` it will stay before `%` symbol

Comment: still the same issue sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255695/discussion-between-mandy8055-and-flyingduck92).

Answer (score 0):

What about seeing it in a different perspective?

[image]

You're trying to put `%` sign inside the string of numbers.

I think **making one more element for the percent sign and putting it next to each other would do the trick.** Use flex to style it then.

Also, it would be helpful if you want to do something with the number value; for instance, you don't need to do extra slicing.